# SearchKit join custom entity reference field fails

Tags: searchkit

I am trying to build a SearchKit query that joins cases with events via a custom reference field inside an activity. So the link is case -> case activity -> event and SearchKit offers me the selection of those entities, however, it fails when displaying the results saying "Invalid field":

> {     "display": {        "error_code": 0,        "error_message": "Invalid field
> 'Gerichtstermin_ausw_hlen.Test'",         "status": 500   } }

Am I doing it wrong or is this a bug?